# MVC3 cannot validate dropdownfor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

Not sure if i'm populating my dropdown correctly but I'm having issue validating the values in my dropdownlist. When a value has been selected it's still showing error 'The value x is invalid'. The type is of int? as I know int doesn't work with the validator.

View model code:

```
[Display(Name = "Category")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Category is required.")]
    public AWS.DTO.Lookup Category { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<AWS.DTO.Lookup> Categories { get; set; }
```

Controller code:

```
[PageOptions(Title = "Create FMR")]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var model = new FMRRequestViewModel();

        model.Categories = new AWS.BL.Lookup().GetFMRCategories();

        return View(model);
    }
```

Lookup Type:

```
public class Lookup
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

View code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Category, new SelectList(Model.Categories, "ID", "Description", -1), "-- Please Select -- ")
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why would you have the `ID` of your `Lookup` class be nullable?

Comment: Because I read that the validator doesn't work with non-nullable types, but as you can see I got it all wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DropDown's don't work that way.  A dropdown can only send the ID, not the text. You are passing the whole Category object to DropDownListFor, which it won't understand.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Category.ID, new SelectList(Model.Categories, "ID", "Description", -1), "-- Please Select -- ")
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not going to bind to a `Lookup` model once selected. MVC doesn't work like ASP where you receive back an object (ASP you'd "bind" an enumerable of objects and, when selected, the whole object was returned--this is not the case in mvc, only the key will be returned (or whatever property was mapped as the dropdown's value)).

Instead you'd have to accept an `Int32` then in your action retrieve the matching `Lookup`. So, in short:

1. change your ViewModel so `Category` is an `Int32`/`int` (and not a `Lookup` object).
2. in the receiving action map the `Lookup` based on what `Category` has for a populated value.